# MongoDB - Limit the number of elements in array based on type (max N elements for each type)

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I would like to create a query that will limit the number of elements to a max `N=2` for each `entityType`.

Besides `entityType` & `entityId`, the original document also has some other properties (eg: `timestamp`) which I simply removed for simplicity.

Here is the **initial/reference** document.

```json
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("100000"),
    "agency" : "agency_1",
    "username" : "user_one",
    "recentEntities" : {
        "entities" : [ 
            {
                "entityType" : "type_one",
                "entityId" : "11",
                "other" : "aa",
            },
            {
                "entityType" : "type_one",
                "entityId" : "12",
                "other" : "ab",
            },
            {
                "entityType" : "type_two",
                "entityId" : "21",
                "other" : "ba",
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Here are 3 specifications/cases for this problem :

- Every time a new entity is added as the **first** element in the `entities` array, meaning most recent visied entity.

Let's say that I want to update the initial document with the following entity :

```
{
    "entityType" : "type_two",
    "entityId" : "22",
    "other" : "bb",
}
```

Since we did not reach the limit for the `"entityType" = "type_two"`, we will simply add the object to the array and the updated document will look like:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("100000"),
    "agency" : "agency_1",
    "username" : "user_one",
    "recentEntities" : {
        "entities" : [ 
            {
                "entityType" : "type_two",
                "entityId" : "22",
                "other" : "bb",
            },
            {
                "entityType" : "type_one",
                "entityId" : "11",
                "other" : "aa",
            },
            {
                "entityType" : "type_one",
                "entityId" : "12",
                "other" : "ab",
            },
            {
                "entityType" : "type_two",
                "entityId" : "21",
                "other" : "ba",
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

- If the document with a particular `entityId` already exists, but the other fields inside the object have changed, then I would like to replace that entity object with the recent one.

Updating the **reference** document with this entity:

```
{
    "entityType" : "type_one",
    "entityId" : "12",
    "other" : "xy",
}
```

Will result in :

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("100000"),
    "agency" : "agency_1",
    "username" : "user_one",
    "recentEntities" : {
        "entities" : [ 
            {
                "entityType" : "type_one",
                "entityId" : "12",
                "other" : "xy",
            },
            {
                "entityType" : "type_one",
                "entityId" : "11",
                "other" : "aa",
            },
            {
                "entityType" : "type_two",
                "entityId" : "21",
                "other" : "ba",
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

- On the other hand, if the limit has been reached, then the oldest entity of a particular type will be deleted.

For example by adding the following entity:

```
{
    "entityType" : "type_one",
    "entityId" : "13",
    "other" : "ac",
}
```

we need to remove the `"entityId" = "12"` and put the new one on top.

After the update, the **reference** document will look like:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("100000"),
    "agency" : "agency_1",
    "username" : "user_one",
    "recentEntities" : {
        "entities" : [ 
            {
                "entityType" : "type_one",
                "entityId" : "13",
                "other" : "ac",
            },
            {
                "entityType" : "type_one",
                "entityId" : "11",
                "other" : "aa",
            },
            {
                "entityType" : "type_two",
                "entityId" : "21",
                "other" : "ba",
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

---

I managed to do the first 2 points, but the last one is a bit tricky to implement so any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the followings in an aggregation pipeline:

1. append the latest entry(i.e entityId 13 to the array by using `$concatArrays`
2. `$unwind` the array with `includeArrayIndex` option. I name the index as `idx`
3. `$sort` by `idx: -1`
4. `$limit` by the count you want(i.e. 3 in your example)
5. `$group` again the entities by `$push`

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      "_id": "100000"
    }
  },
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "recentEntities.entities": {
        "$concatArrays": [
          "$recentEntities.entities",
          [
            {
              "entityType": "type_one",
              "entityId": "13",
              "other": "ac",
              
            }
          ]
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$unwind": {
      path: "$recentEntities.entities",
      includeArrayIndex: "idx"
    }
  },
  {
    "$sort": {
      idx: -1
    }
  },
  {
    $limit: 3
  },
  {
    "$sort": {
      idx: 1
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$_id",
      "agency": {
        $first: "$agency"
      },
      "username": {
        $first: "$username"
      },
      "re": {
        $push: "$recentEntities.entities"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "agency": 1,
      "username": 1,
      "recentEntities": {
        entities: "$re"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Here is the [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/R2DOkNFxnOE) for your reference.